# On the Complete integrability of a tangent distribution

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, reference-request

Reading about the geometrical theory of systems of first order pdes, I have met a result from symplectic geometry, that is easy to prove, but I am unable to give a reference for it.  So my question is:

> Where could I find a reference to the following easy result?

Let $W$ be a coisotropic embedded submanifold of a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$.
Let $T_W M$ be the restriction to $W$ of the tangent bundle of $M$.
In the symplectic vector bundle $(T_W M,\omega|_{T_W M})$, let the symplectic complement of $TW$ be denoted by $(TW)^\perp$.

Then $(TW)^\perp$, being a vector subbundle of $TW$ because of the coisotropy of $W$, is completely integrable.

Comment: I don't know an explicit reference to this exact statement, but doesn't this follow directly from Darboux' theorem?  After all, $(TW)^\perp\subset TW$ is the null space of the pullback of the closed $2$-form $\omega$ to $W$, and Darboux' theorem gives that this null space is integrable.  There are many places you can see this statement, but, for example, if you look at what I called Darboux' Reduction Theorem in my Park City Lectures, you'll see this exact statement.

Comment: Dear Robert Bryant, thanks very much for your attention.  If I had wait a moment before to post the question, perhaps I could have remembered of the Darboux' reduction theorem in your lectures or of the equivalent Propositions 5.1.2-3 in Foundations of Mechanics by A&M, but I have preferred to get an occasion to communicate with others on the subject I try to learn.  Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an exercise in McDuff and Salamon's *Introduction to Symplectic Topology*.  In the second edition, it's exercise 3.29.  I don't know if an exercise is a great reference, but I've seen them used before.

Comment: Dear Jordan Watts, thank you for the reference. Sure it works well and, by the way, hints a proof as the one that initially I have thought.